# what's the use of `State<T extends StatefulWidget>`

Tags: flutter, oop, dart

I looked at the docs of dart for generics.

```
abstract class StringCache {
  String getByKey(String key);
  void setByKey(String key, String value);
}

abstract class ObjectCache {
  Object getByKey(String key);
  void setByKey(String key, Object value);
}
```

The above two is replaceed by one single generic type T with below code

```
abstract class Cache<T> {
  T getByKey(String key);
  void setByKey(String key, T value);
}
```

Where the use of     `T` is seen clearly. but not sure where the state class uses

```
class _CounterState extends State<Counter> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _increment() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: _increment,
          child: Text('Increment'),
        ),
        Text('Count: $_counter'),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not a java person but in C# there something called constraints in Generics. `State<T extends StatefulWidget>` look similar to me. It means `State` can accept only `T`s which are `StatefulWidget` or inherited/extended from `StatefulWidget`. From looking at your code it looks like `Counter` in `State<Counter>` is inherited/extended from `StatefulWidget` type.

Comment: can you help on how `T` is injected in the `State` since there is no field of type `T` or method with output as `T` or arguments with `T`. I am not seeing where it's been injected/used by State class.

Comment: `State` does not have to have any field or method which deals with `T`. It might have internal logic where it is using specific property of method of `T`. When you have `T extends StatefulWidget` constraint, `State` class has access to all the methods, properties, events of `StatefulWidget` type. If you can share the code of `State` class, I can point that out.

Answer (score 3):

`T` is a generic type parameter and `extends StatefulWidget` is a constraint for what types `T` can be set to.

With

```
class _CounterState extends State<Counter> {
```

`T` is set to type `Counter` (which has to be a `StatefulWidget`).

Passing `Counter` as type allows you to use

```
widget.foo
```

to reference field `foo` in `Counter` from `_CounterState` and you get autocompletion and static type checking.